# SQL: Find the Max of Sums in a range of time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like the following:

```
Date      | Value
---------------------
01-01-2015| 65.000,00
01-01-2015| 15.032,00
01-01-2015| 25.200,00
01-01-2015| 45.000,00
02-01-2015| 34.500,00
02-01-2015| 65.056,00
02-01-2015| 65.700,00
02-01-2015|  6.000,00
```

In the table I have records of transactions for different dates. Now I want to find the day with the biggest Sum(value) for Dates between 01/2015 and 07/2015.

In other words, the day with the highest income ever.

How can this be achieved? So far I have only found away of selecting the day biggest value recorded and not the Sum of them all. The database is in PostgresSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `group by`, with some additional logic to get the biggest value.  Here is the approach using `oder by` and `limit`:

```
select date, sum(value) as sumvalue
from table t
group by date
order by sumvalue desc
limit 1;
```